# Помогите с setStyleSheet()

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qss

Допустим у меня есть приложение PyQt5, в котором надо изменить background кнопки pushButton на чёрный. Я ещё не совсем мыслю в PyQt5, поэтому возникла проблема с setStyleSheet(). Как в данном случае, в вышеуказанной кнопке, изменить background с помощью функции setStyleSheet()? Вот мой код, обработанный с Qt designer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(887, 891)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 771, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 240, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 300, 771, 511))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Comment: Советую почитать про Компоновщики (Layout'ы). Например есть QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout. Они позволят размещать виджеты без привязки к конкретным пикселям и размерам. Компоновщики автоматически меняют размер. В дизайнере это будет наглядно выглядеть. Вот пример виджета, с формой из дизайнера: https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window/tree/master Если откроете его ui файл, то увидите и поймете

Comment: Дело в том что я до этого изучал веб технологии ( html, css ), поэтому мне намного легче и привычней будет использовать css. Но за ответ спасибо, обязательно попробую.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После того как файл формы был сгенерирован в `py` (пусть будет `mainwindow_ui.py`) его нужно "применить" для виджета.

Создаем класс виджета и в нем вызываем `setupUi` из `Ui_MainWindow` передав указатель на себя.

Для доступа к виджетам из формы обращайтесь к переменной `ui`.

Много примеров по стилям есть в [официальной документации](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html).

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background: black;')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    
    app.exec()
```

Для более сложного описания стилей можно многострочные литералы использовать, например:

```
self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet('''
    background-color: red;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: beige;
    font: bold 14px;
    min-width: 10em;
    padding: 6px;
''')
```

Также стили можно применять не к конкретным виджетам, а к всему приложению ([app.setStyleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop)), или к окну, и тогда все виджеты на нем получат стили ([mw.setStyleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop)), поэтому в стилях можно указывать конкретные типы виджетов или их объектные имена (object name):

> ```
> QTextEdit, QListView {
>     background-color: white;
>     background-image: url(draft.png);
>     background-attachment: scroll;
> }
> ```

---

Примерный скриншот будет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за такую подробную информацию.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)